# ansible using hostname as a condition

Tags: ansible

I have an HA setup that I am building.  I am using Ansible 2.9.11. I need to search the hostname and if it is the b side copy the backup config over.  I have tried the following code and it is not working.  Or is there a different way to accomplish this?

> [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating
> delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: 'b' in {{ inventory_hostname
> }} fatal: [dev-sca02b]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''b'
> in {{ inventory_hostname }}' failed. The error was: error while
> evaluating conditional ('b' in {{ inventory_hostname }}): 'dev' is
> undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in
> '/Users/user1/Documents/Ansible/sca_fusion.yaml': line 134, column 5,
> but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
> problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: "Change
> keepalived to backup"\n    ^ here\n"}

```
  - name: "Change keepalived to backup"
    replace:
      path: /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
      regexp: "MASTER"
      replace: "BACKUP"
    when: "'b' in {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That warning should point you to the main source of your problem:

> WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.

A `when` condition is already in an implicit jinja templating context, so you don't need to create one explicitly. You want:

```
  - name: "Change keepalived to backup"
    replace:
      path: /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
      regexp: "MASTER"
      replace: "BACKUP"
    when: "'b' in inventory_hostname"
```